# selenium webdriver to get visible row number in table

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am writing test script using selenium webdriver and java for page which has a table with multiple rows column. This rows has same style and class. However, some of rows are hidden and some of them are displayed on page. There are ~1800 rows from which only seven rows are displayed on page. Now, I have to work on visible row for process data, I have created xpath but it is taking very long time to verify which row number is visible on page and if visible than proceed further with running script else check next row. This I have achieved by using for loop but it is too time consuming. Well there is a drop down option in rows but the id of those drop down is dynamic based on table row like testid_0 - row 1, testid_1 - row 2. My question is there any way we can get the visible row number of table like row 7, row 100, row 500 which is visible on page without spending time or using for loop? or can we get the javascript which run using selenium and return the number of row which are displayed on page.

Comment: How rows are hidden? Using `style="display:none;"` in `tr`?

Comment: Yes Ruslan, it has same style as you mention (class="row" style="display: none;") in tr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter invisible `tr` using proper `xpath`, like:

`//table/tbody/tr[not(contains(@style,'display: none;'))]`

Comment: I tried this and it also gives me visible row. However, I have to work on tr/td data. That is if tr is visible than get the data of each td, like tr/td[1]/span/text(), tr/td[2]/span/text() based on the text I have to select option from drop down which is available in same tr/td[7]. the xpath example which you have given will give me data available in tr, but how I will select option from drop down from same tr?

Comment: You can get `List<WebElement>` using my xpath and then work with every element using xpaths like `./td[1]/span/text()`

Comment: So the final xpath query will something like: //table/tbody/tr[not(contains(@style,'display: none;'))]/td[1]/span/text() this.. OK, let me try it and I appreciate your help and inputs. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the below code to get the count of rows that are visible(**Assuming there is just one table in the webpage**):

```
int count = 0;
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr"));
for(WebElement row: rows){
  if(row.isDisplayed())
    count++;
}
System.out.println("The number of rows that are visible is: "+ count);
```

Comment: I tried this and it takes lots of time to find all the visible rows in table, it takes around 5min to verify all 1800 rows of table. However, @Ruslan inputs are working very fast and gives required outputs... :)

Comment: Oh! It's just an alternative anyway. And, I agree, @Ruslan's the effective one.. :)